# Active Record Scope: Only include if all joined models match where statement

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following scope for customers:

```
scope :filter, -> {
    joins(:subscriptions)
    .where("subscriptions.end_date <= ?", 1.year.ago.to_date)
  }
```

This scope works fine if customers have one subscriptions less than one year but if they have 2 subscriptions and one is greater than a year and one is less than a year, it still is included in this scope.

How do I write the scope to NOT include the customer if one of the subscriptions doesn't match the where statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could probably do a subquery where you count the number of subscriptions > 1.year.ago, and compare that count to 0
It would look something like this

```
scope :filter, -> {
  joins(:subscriptions)
    .where("subscriptions.end_date <= ?", 1.year.ago.to_date)
    .where("(select count(subscriptions.id) from subscriptions where subscriptions.customer_id = id && subscriptions.end_date > ?) = 0", 1.year.ago.to_date)
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for, is the first where really necessary with this new query?

Comment: The first where insures that they have atleast 1 that is over a year old, the second ensures that they have none less than a year old.

So it depends on the use case you are trying to accomplish, if you just want to get customers who haven't been subscribed in a year, then no. but if we want customers that used to be subscribed, but haven't for a year, then yes